# Можно ли изменить факты по ходу выполнения?

Tags: prolog

Факт:

```
запас(уголь , 5).

взять_товар(X) :- 
запас(X,Y) , integer(Y) , Y > 0 , запас(уголь,Y-1).
```

Есть запас угля 5 мешков.
После вызова предиката взять_товар(уголь), должно остаться 4 мешка угля 
Должно выйти:

```
?- взять_товар(уголь),запас(уголь,X).
X==4.
```

1. Как лучше хранить динамически изменяемые факты?
2. это правильный подход или нужно использовать глобальные переменные nb_setval nb_getval, или что то еще?

Answer (score 1):

Объявите предикат `запас/2` динамическим и используйте `assert`/`retract`.